# What does とも mean and how to use it

Tags: grammar, particles

On Lang-8 I wrote I a journal entry.
I wrote

> その後で、兄が買ったトランプをしました。三回をして、三回を勝ちました。

This got corrected to

> その後で、兄が買ったトランプをしました。三回をして、三回**とも**勝ちました。

What does とも mean here? And how do I use this particle. Does it put emphasis or does it express something else? I tried looking it up but I could not find much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「とも」, in that context, means "***all (of)***".

So, 「三回{さんかい}とも勝{か}ちました」 means "I won all three times."

The format is:

> 「Number + Counter Word + とも」

You can say 「5人{にん}とも」("all of the 5 people")、「4匹{ひき}とも」("all of the 4 dogs, cats, etc."), etc.

Nothing to do with your question, but 「三回をして」 is incorrect.  It is 「三回して」 without the 「を」.  "did it three times", "played three times", etc.